# Event startDateTime shows more timestamp on Production

Tags: apex, datetime, timezone

I have assigned custom timestamp to "starDateTime" standard field of event object by concatenating to custom date field but it shows additional 5:30 hours on Production.It works better in sandbox. I have following peace of code:

```
String selectedTime='09:00 to 09:30'
string selectedDate='2019/10/1 00:00:00';
event.DurationInMinutes=30;
System.debug('selectedTime '+selectedTime);
string conTime = selectedTime.substring(0,5);
string conDate = selectedDate.substring(0,10);
selectedDate =selectedDate+' '+conTime+':00';
Datetime convertedDate = Datetime.valueOf(selectedDate);
event.Time_Slot__c=selectedTime;
event.StartDateTime= convertedDate;
insert event;
```

Above code gives right time in Start 9:00 and End 9:30 in event record but in production it shows 2:30 to 3:00. Please suggest any solution.Thanks!

Comment: Set the time in GMT format, you may have different time zones set on Production and Sandbox.

Comment: We have same time zone in production as well as in sandbox still getting problem.I have set time zone in company information from setup